# What is the best way to check if an employee is assigned for particular period - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

My employee table contains three columns 'job_date', 'job_start_time' and 'job_end_time'. From my asp.net web application, I have entered the time for these three columns using sql queries (job_date=current date, job_start_time=10:00 AM, job_end_time=2.00 PM). So it means this employee is busy for 10:00 AM to 2.00 PM for the entered date. So when I try to assign a new job for same employee within a time period between this interval (say between 11:30 AM to 12:30 PM) system should alert that employee is already busy for another job. What is the best query to test there is already a job is assigned for this employee?

```
SELECT emp_id,job_date,job_start_time,job_end_time FROM employees WHERE emp_id='EMP001'

emp_id    job_date     job_start_time   job_end_time 
EMP001   17-03-2021       10:00 AM         2.00 PM
```

Comment: What has this got to do with C#? Are you using an ORM? More detail please: tables, sample data, expected output

Comment: when user send new time ranges to the same employee, it should check on dataabse if  that employee will be busy for that time schedule. If then sql should return a value.

Comment: What is the field type of start and end time?

Comment: @TheMixy  Now  job_date ,job_start_time,job_end_time all are set as date_time. For to achieve above requirement, it can change accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's presume a new job is defined with two datetime fields and `emp_id` (you have to pass all three as parameters from your code):

```sql
-- new job is on 2021-03-17 10AM : 2021-03-17 12AM
DECLARE @jobStart datetime = '2021-03-17 10:00 AM'
DECLARE @jobEnd datetime = '2021-03-17 11:30 AM'
```

EDIT: as per comments below I have update the SQL.

You than have to check, if any falls within existing intervals:

```sql
SELECT emp_id
FROM employees
WHERE emp_id = @emp_id
    AND (@jobStart BETWEEN job_date + job_start_time AND job_date + job_end_time 
        OR @jobEnd BETWEEN job_date + job_start_time AND job_date + job_end_time
        OR (@jobStart < job_date + job_start_time AND @jobEnd > job_date + job_end_time)
    );
```

if the query returns any records you know the employee is busy.

Comment: @user2431727 . . . This logic is not correct.  It does not take into account users that start before the time period and then end afterwards.  In addition, by assuming that the date/time are combined in a single column, it doesn't address the data described in the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: you are correct. I have made an update

Answer (score 0):

To return employees that have conflicts with the time period (which seems to be what you want):

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
WHERE emp_id = @emp_id AND
      job_date = @job_date AND
      job_start_time < @job_end_time AND
      job_end_time > @job_start_time;
```

Comment: but here you assume that a new job always spans over only one day. If it's over 2 or more days, the SQL will not work... but I see such is the users model. OK.

Comment: @TheMixy . . . This is not an *assumption*.  That is the structure of the data.

Comment: I realized that after posting my comment :)